# memory menagement in ios

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Can anybody explain me why does the case1 and case2 crashes while the others does not in case of non-ARC?

```
Case1:
    NSString *rr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"AB"];
    [rr release];
    [rr autorelease];

Case2:
    NSString *rrr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"AB"];
    [rrr autorelease];
    [rrr release];

Case3:
    NSMutableString *rr1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"AB"];
    [rr1 release];
    [rr1 autorelease];

Case4:
    NSMutableString *rrr1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"AB"];
    [rrr1 autorelease];
    [rrr1 release];

Case5:
    NSArray *rr3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jj", nil];
    [rr3 release];
    [rr3 autorelease];

Case6:
    NSArray *rrr3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jj", nil];
    [rrr3 autorelease];
    [rrr3 release];

Case7:
    NSMutableArray *rr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jj", nil];
    [rr2 release];
    [rr2 autorelease];

Case8:
    NSMutableArray *rr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jj", nil];
    [rr2 autorelease];
    [rr2 release];
```

Comment: I think you've described the situation backwards. The first and second should not crash while the others should. Anyway, I would recommend reading the [memory management documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). That document explains everything, and it almost certainly does it better than anyone here will. If you're unclear about something after reading the docs, ask about that — asking people to rewrite the docs for you on Stack Overflow isn't a great idea for anyone involved.

Comment: @Zaph: Because unless Apple has flipped the script while I wasn't looking, constant strings are not created or destroyed. They ignore releases and simply return themselves when you retain or copy them.

Comment: @Chuck, Yes, you are correct! I wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: None of these are correct. You should either `release` or `autorelease`, but not both. I'm not sure why one would care why doing one thing incorrectly results in a crash and doing something else incorrectly doesn't. Just because it didn't crash doesn't make it right. Certainly don't write code that relies upon the over-releasing of objects to not crash in certain circumstances.

Comment: Actually this was an interview question that was asked to me and I am not sure that whats the correct answer for it.So,I thought of asking it here.So,could anyone confirm me the correct answer for future reference.

Comment: Moreover,Iran the code in Xcode and the 1st and 2nd case was crashing while the other's were not.So,was just confirming.

Answer (score 3):

All are are incorrect because eventually all will be released twice, but some may coincidentally not crash.

The `alloc` allocates the object with a retain count of 1. `release` decreases the retain count 1. `autorelease` eventually decreases the retain count 1. That means that all are over released.

But as @Chuck mentions some instances are constants, are created at compile time and never released so `release` and `autorelease` can be called to many tines with no crash.

String constants are one instance of this this where over-releasing will not cause a crash:
`NSString *s = @"aa";`
Even over-releasing this is OK because the compiler is smart enough:
`NSString *s = [NSString stringWithString:@"aa"];`
But you will get a warning from the current LLVM compiler that using `stringWithString` with a literal is redundant.

Comment: What is "con stances"? I think you meant "constants".

Comment: I'd phrase it as "all are incorrect, but some may coincidentally not crash".

Comment: @Greg reworded to follow your comment.